# Investigate convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Investigate convergence of:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)}$$

Now I know by $p$-series test this summation converges however, is there a way to prove that this series converges by some manipulation and then using the comparison test?

Comment: $n\neq1$ question of convergence meaningless.

Comment: Yes sorry it is meant to be 2

Comment: Well $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\leq\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{1}{n\left(n-1\right)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$$
What does it tell you?

Comment: Well yeah I know this, it well actually give a value for the sum (I got it converges to 1) however is there a way of using the comparison test?

Comment: When working with the comparison test, it is usually good to look for bounds of the form $\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$. Here, try $\frac{1}{n^2}$ with appropriate constants. (By the way, if you know the sum of a series it's even better than finding out using a comparison test)

Comment: I tried using $\frac{1}{n^2}$ however if I compare that with the series we see that doesnt work since the series will be larger than the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ series hence I cannot use that series.

Comment: Try using the fact that $n(n - 1) \geq (n - 1)^{2}$.